# Finding the coefficient of static friction for coin on a turn table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, centripetal-force

The question I have is:

> A coin is placed 1$2.0 cm$ from the axis of a rotating turn table of
>   variable speed. When the speed of the turn table is slowly increased,
>   the coin remains fixed on the table until a rate of $35.0\space rpm$
>   is reached, at which point the coin slides off. What is the
>   coefficient of static friction between the coin and the table?

I found $v=\frac{2\pi r}{T}=\frac{2\pi (0.12 cm)}{0.58333...rev/s}=1.2925m/s$

and

$a_R=\frac{v^2}{r}= 13.922m/s^2$

I know that $\mu_sF_n = F_{fr}$, but that's the only relation for $\mu$ that I have and I'm not sure how to get from the info I have to any of that since there was no coin mass given in the problem. Can someone give me some guidance on where to go with this?

Comment: 35 rev/s is your angular velocity how did you use it here as time

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311134/friction-coupling-dish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all 35 rev/s is angular velocity and not time.

So velocity of coin(v)$=r×w$(angular velocity)
                                     $=0.12×(35×\frac{2\pi}{60})$
                                     =0.44

So centripetal force = $\dfrac{mv^2}{r}$

Coin will start sliding when friction reached maximum value so no more force can be provided.

So friction =$(\mu)N$
                   =$(\mu)mg$

So $\dfrac{mv^2}r$=$mg(\mu)$
      $\dfrac{v^2}r$ =$g(\mu)$

So coefficient of friction$(\mu)$=$\dfrac{v^2}{(rg)}$

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: Hi,you can make equations look more better. For example e=mc^2 can  make better as $e=mc^2$ and another example: e^i π =  -1 as $e^{i \pi} = -1$. Just by using [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes I am learning use of mathjax

Comment: You can improve (add Mathjax) your previous posts by editing. For this question,go [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/314879/edit)

Comment: I did it but the howto work it for Greek letters.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot i used it for the first time.

Comment: Greek letters have special commands. To add an $\alpha$, you write `$\alpha$`. To add a $\theta$, you write `$\theta$`.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the centripetal force which includes a mass term. Since the coin is at rest, the FBD of the coin shows that centripetal force has to be equal in magnitude to the frictional force. You can find the normal reaction, which also includes a mass term. Equating the friction[coefficient times normal reaction] to the centripetal force, the mass terms get cancelled.